# Why is the format declared twice in font-face using 'format('extension_here')'

Tags: css

When using font-face i have allways been wondering if it is really necessary to add the part about format for example 'format('eot')'? It seems like declaring the format twice and a waste of time and code.

Do anyone have a good explanation why it is done this way? And if it is ok just leave it out?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font_name';
  src: url('Font_name.eot?') format('eot'), url('Font_name.woff') format('woff'),  url('Font_name.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: I think the format is the format of the font not really the extension or anything to do with the url extension of the font -- take a look at this info --- http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

Comment: I agree. But do browsers really need that info and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `format(...)` part is, by definition, *the* part that declares the font format. Whatever the `url(...)` part contains is just a URL, a string used to access a resource. In practice browsers may, in the absence of properly declared information, try to guess the content type of a resource from the last few characters of the URL used to access it, but this is not a good excuse for not writing proper declarations.

The definition of the [`src` descriptor](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#src-desc) says:

> External references consist of a URL, followed by an optional hint
>   describing the format of the font resource referenced by that URL. The
>   format hint contains a comma-separated list of format strings that
>   denote well-known font formats. Conformant user agents must skip
>   downloading a font resource if the format hints indicate only
>   unsupported or unknown font formats. If no format hints are supplied,
>   the user agent should download the font resource.

So if you omit the `format(...)` part, browsers will download the font resource—they are *not* expected to analyze the URL before doing that. This may mean considerable inefficiency, since browsers will download resources they cannot handle; only after downloading, say, an EOT font resource will they look at its content and see they cannot handle it and must download the next resource in the list.

Answer (score 0):

**`eot`** **embedded-opentype** format is basically used for IE Browser.

So this is the rule to target the older version of IE Browser. All latest browser have support for `woff` font format.

Here is the CSS Rule if using `custom font` for web.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Comment: Please read my question again - im not asking about '.eot' but how formats are declared in font-face generally..